# Issue with WordPress RSS Feed Generation in My Website

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

I am encountering a problem related to the RSS feed generation on my WordPress website, specifically with the Rishi theme. Despite following standard procedures and troubleshooting steps, the RSS feed for my website is not being generated or access.

**Problem Description:**

The symptoms I'm experiencing include:

When attempting to access the RSS feed by visiting '[https://techconte.com/feed/](https://stackoverflow.com)'.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps, such as switching to a default WordPress theme, deactivating plugins, checking for code errors, and updating permalinks, but none of these actions have resolved the issue.

Additional Information:

I have ensured that the RSS feed is enabled by default in WordPress.
There are no visible error messages in the WordPress dashboard.
I have attempted to manually implement RSS feed links and code into my theme's header.php file, but this did not resolve the problem.

**WordPress Environment**:

- WordPress Version: Latest Version
- Theme Name: Rishi
- Plugin Used: Rank Math, WP Rocket.
- Hosting Provider: Hostinger

How to identify and resolve this issue with RSS feed generation in the Rishi theme?